# How can I find names of colors which are incluced in Python palette='bright'?

Tags: bar-chart, palette

I made a barplot graph using palette='bright' to define colors of bars. I would like to use these same colors for other graph, so can I find somewhere the names of colors which are included in palette 'bright'?

(I can't use a palette for my stacked bar chart, so it will be helpful to know the names of colors)

My barplot graph code:

```
 sns.set(style="whitegrid")
    ax = sns.barplot(x="genotyp", y="mean", hue='gen', data=data,
                 palette='bright', ci="sd")
```

My stacked bar chart:

```
 bars1 = [0.87, 5.23]
    bars2 = [7.84, 22.59]
    bars3 = [91.29, 72.18]
    bars = np.add(bars1, bars2).tolist()
    r = [0.5, 1]
    names = ['boy','girl']
    barWidth = 0.25
    # Create first bars
    p1=plt.bar(r, bars1, color='gold', edgecolor='none', width=barWidth)
    # Create second bars (middle), on top of the firs ones
    p2=plt.bar(r, bars2, bottom=bars1, color='#3cb44b', edgecolor='none', 
    width=barWidth)
    # Create third bars (top)
    p3=plt.bar(r, bars3, bottom=bars, color='steelblue', edgecolor='none', 
    width=barWidth)
```

I would like both graph to have the same colors (colors which are included in the palette bright), but I don´t know how to manage it.

Thank you

Comment: Hi Klara, welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful if you could give us a minimal, working example. i.e: Needed libraries, some dummy data and your plot commands so everybody can reproduce what you are doing. It is than more clear what you are doing - and from this Point on it is easier to help you with your Palette Color Question.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a reference to CSS named colors. The colors in your code appear to be standard CSS values, nothing specific to Python. Example:

```html
<h1 style="color:steelblue;">I am Steel Blue!!</h1>
```

Here is a nice reference for all the named CSS colors: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/named-colors-and-hex-equivalents/

Comment: Yes this is quite what I wanted, but also I would like to find out names of colors which are included in defined palette called bright in python, so I can you then these colors the way you suggested. Because I wasn´t able to find anywhere.